# I can't login to google for xamarin project?

Tags: xamarin, authentication, google-signin

In my login process with Xamarin, I got the error that google was "canceled". Are there any resolvers?

Hata Code 9001. Something went wrong. SIGN_IN_CANCELLED

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show us what you're doing.  Post the relevant code.

Comment: @Jason I am sorry.